# DllImport - PreserverSig and SetLastError attributes

Tags: interop, dllimport

On the MSDN I've found the following description for the two attributes:

**PreserveSig** Set the PreserveSig field to true to directly translate unmanaged signatures with HRESULT or retval values; set it to false to automatically convert HRESULT or retval values to exceptions. By default, the PreserveSig field is true.

**SetLastError** Enables the caller to use the Marshal.GetLastWin32Error API function to determine whether an error occurred while executing the method. In Visual Basic, the default is true (which adds some overhead); in C# and C++, the default is false.

My question is: How these two relate to each other? Suppose I have PreserveSig set to 'false' - it means that I should have HRESULT converted to exception - if unmanaged function returns integer indicating that error or no error occured, how could this be translated to exception?

Also why do I need to call GetLastWin32Error method if I somehow managed to extract the exception using PreserveSig?

Kind regards
PK

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Win32 functions almost never return a `HRESULT`. Instead they return a `BOOL` or use special values to indicate error (e.g. `CreateFile` returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`). They store the error code in a per-thread variable, which you can read with `GetLastError()`. `SetLastError=true` instructs the marshaler to read this variable after the native function returns, and stash the error code where you can later read it with `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()`. The idea is that the .NET runtime may call other Win32 functions behind the scenes which mess up the error code from your p/invoke call before you get a chance to inspect it.

Functions which return a `HRESULT` (or equivalent, e.g. `NTSTATUS`) belong to a different level of abstraction than Win32 functions. Generally these functions are COM-related (above Win32) or from `ntdll` (below Win32), so they don't use the Win32 last-error code (they might call Win32 functions internally, though).

`PreserveSig=false` instructs the marshaler to check the return `HRESULT` and if it's not a success code, to create and throw an exception containing the `HRESULT`. The managed declaration of your `DllImport`ed function then has `void` as its return type.

Remember, the C# or VB compiler cannot check the `DllImport`ed function's unmanaged signature, so it has to trust whatever you tell it. If you put `PreserveSig=false` on a function which returns something other than a `HRESULT`, you will get strange results (e.g. random exceptions). If you put `SetLastError=true` on a function which does not set the last Win32 error code, you will get garbage instead of a useful error code.

Comment: I dont have experience with COM objects so let me ask one more question regarding creation of method signature. The question is: when I see that COM function returns HRESULT I can mark my method as returning void and set PreserveSig=false (as you said), or set PreserveSig=true and mark my method as returning IntPtr to manually examine the returned code?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, except that HRESULTs are UInt32s, not IntPtrs.

Comment: Thank you - you have been very helpful.

Comment: "If you put `SetLastError=true` on a function which does not set the last Win32 error code, you will get garbage instead of a useful error code." - OK, but how can we determine if a Win32 function does set the Win32 thread-local error code? The official documentation for most Windows functions I see doesn't mention anything about if they set the last-error code or not, e.g. [example 1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-pathyetanothermakeuniquename) or [example 2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathfindonpathw)

Comment: If the documentation for a function `F` doesn't mention it setting last error code, [like here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew#return-value), then `F` doesn't set last error code by itself. `F` may call other Win32 functions internally so the last error code may be set to something informative if `F` fails (call `SetLastError(SUCCESS)` before calling `F` to clear the last error code), but I think it's a bad idea to rely on that.